# Python function call within a property of a class

Tags: python, function

I am trying to use the `"setx"` function of a `Property` in a `Class` to do some processing of date information that I get from excel.  I have a few of my own functions that do the data processing which I tested outside the class, and they worked just fine.  But when I move them into the class they suddenly become invisible unless I use the `self.` instance first.  When I use the `self.My_xldate_as_tuple()` method I get an error:

```
My_xldate_as_tuple() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Even though the code is EXACTLY what i used outside the class before and it worked.

Before moving into the `Property Set` block, I was doing the processing of date data outside of the class and setting the variables from outside of the class.  That gets clunky when I have about 15 different operations that are all based on when the `NumDates Property` change.  I'm showing shortened versions of both the working set of code and the non-working set of code.  What is going on with the `self.` call that changes how the function takes inputs?

Broken Code:

```
class XLDataClass(object):

    _NumDates = []
    TupDates = []

    def getNumDates(self): return self._NumDates    
    def setNumDates(self, value): 
        self._NumDates = value
        self.TupDates = list(map(self.My_xldate_as_tuple,value)) #Error here

        #This version doesn't work either, since it can't find My_xldate_as_tuple anymore
        self.TupDates = list(map(My_xldate_as_tuple,value))

    def delNumDates(self):del self._NumDates
    NumDates = property(getNumDates,setNumDates,delNumDates,"Ordinal Dates")

    #exact copy of the My_xldate_as_tuple function that works outside the class
    def My_xldate_as_tuple(Date):
        return xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(Date,1)

    #Other code and functions here
#end XlDataClass

def GetExcelData(filename,rowNum,titleCol):
    csv = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter= ",")
    NumDates = deque(csv[rowNum,:])
    if titleCol == True:
        NumDates.popleft()
    return NumDates

#Setup
filedir = "C:/Users/blahblahblah"
filename = filedir + "/SamplePandL.csv"
xlData = XLDataClass()

#Put csv data into xlData object
xlData.NumDates= GetExcelData(filename,0,1)
```

Working Code:

```
class XLDataClass(object):

    NumDates = []
    TupDates = []

    #Other code and functions here
#end XlDataClass

#exact copy of the same function outside of the class, which works here
def My_xldate_as_tuple(Date):
    return xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(Date,1)

def GetExcelData(filename,rowNum,titleCol):
    csv = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter= ",")
    NumDates = deque(csv[rowNum,:])
    if titleCol == True:
        NumDates.popleft()
    return NumDates

#Setup
filedir = "C:/Users/blahblahblah"
filename = filedir + "/SamplePandL.csv"
xlData = XLDataClass()

#Put csv data into xlData object
xlData.NumDates = GetExcelData(filename,0,1)
#same call to the function that was inside the Setx Property of the class, but it works here.
xlData.TupDates = list(map(self.My_xldate_as_tuple,value))
```

Comment: Why are you passing `self` to all of the other methods but not to `My_xldate_as_tuple`?

Comment: ok that's interesting... If I add `self` as the first argument of my custom function within the class it starts to work.  Why on earth does that happen?  I pass `self` to the setx/getx functions because that's what the documentation said I needed to do for the `Properties` function to work.

Comment: That's what you need to do for **every** method in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance methods in Python require an explicit self in the argument list. Inside the class, you need to write your method definition like:

```
def My_xldate_as_tuple(self, Date):
```

Comment: Thank you Robin, I tested the fix and it worked.  Can you explain why that is?  I would think that the context of the class would handle that automatically.

Comment: It's a design decision that the Python developers made early on. Here's an article straight from the man himself (Guido created Python): http://neopythonic.blogspot.ch/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html